# Plugin's action URL not working and showing 404 error

Tags: plugin-development, controller, elementaction

I created a plugin to schedule some custom email notifications. The action URL is working perfectly on localhost but isn't working on stagings server. Is it related to any server stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There's a 99% chance you're running into a case-sensitivity issue on your file system.

Check your plugin's name, the handle and the action URL for the controller you're trying to hit.

Most likely locally, you've got a case insensitive file system, so it doesn't matter that `pluGiNHanDlE` is not equal to `pluginHandle`, but on staging it's case sensitive so it does.

Comment: Thanks Brad... but I pushed the same plugin files to staging and copying the same URI from localhost :(.

Comment: If it's a case sensitivity problem, that would address the issue, though.  Check the names of your plugin files vs. the names of the classes they are declaring.